# Tabularray: Alignment and width of merged cell's headers

Tags: tables, alignment, tabularray

I want to produce a table with merged cells with tabularray. The minimal example looks like that:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{},
  cell{2}{3} = {c=3}{},
  colspec = {ll|ccc},
  columns = {valign = m}
}
\toprule
& \textbf{Attacker}  & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Content}} & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Metadata}} & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Profiling}} \\
\midrule
Architecture A & User A      & Only in proximity of the victim.  &            & \\
& User B      & \checkmark                        & \checkmark &  \checkmark\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

The merged cells content belongs to the "Content", "Metadata" and "Profiling" columns. Currently, as you can see, the "Content" and "Metadata" column have their minimum width, and the "Profiling" column extends as far as the content of the merged cell is. What can I do, so that they all have the same width and align centered? Is there another possibility than manual specifying their width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `hspan=even` option to distribute them *evenly*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  cell{2}{1} = {r=2}{},
  cell{2}{3} = {c=3}{},
  colspec = {ll|ccc},
  columns = {valign = m},
  hspan=even
}
\toprule
& \textbf{Attacker}  & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Content}} & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Metadata}} & \rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Profiling}} \\
\midrule
Architecture A & User A      & Only in proximity of the victim.  &            & \\
& User B      & \checkmark                        & \checkmark &  \checkmark\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]